# Weighted least squares: how do I find weights

Tags: regression, weighted-regression, weights

I have a dataset of the cars and their corresponding speed and distance and the R output. I am asked to find weights for the first 2 cars.

First I find the residual for each car: $e_i=Y_i-\hat{Y}_i$

Then  $w_1=\frac{1}{e_1^2}$  $w_2=\frac{1}{e_2^2}$

Weights are given by  $w_i=\frac{1}{\hat{s}^2_i}$ where $\hat{s}^2_i$ is fitted value from standard deviation.

Is this correct?

Comment: If you could comment on the type of weighting protocol you would like to apply, this will help people prepare a response.

Comment: weights are equal to $$w_i=\frac{1}{\hat{s}^2_i}$$